# Exchange Online: Would messages blocked by a mailflow rule (deleted without notification) show in a Message Trace?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, hosted-exchange

Question on Microsoft Hosted Exchange:
There are a bunch of mail flow rules and we are troubleshooting an issue with a missing incoming message (from outside the org).

There is absolutely no trace of this message incoming from a message trace (Mail Flow -> Message trace) -- even a domain wide trace. Other emails ARE being delivered from this domain.

In case we have to audit our mail flow rules - would a rule (to block/delete a message) cause the message in question to not be shown in a message trace?

thanks!

Comment: Do you still have doubts about this issue? If the issue has been resolved, please accept the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any email processed by a transport rule will be available in a message trace. The message trace will show you the action taken on the email (such as being dropped).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what joeqwerty has replied above, I have done a test in my lab, the deleted mails show in message trace, look like blow:

[image]